# How to create a redirect page For a SharePoint online List Form modern

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

I'm looking at using Modern OOTB list form. But my question is does the redirect url trick still works by using the **?Source** parameter.
This is for Modern SharePoint
For example like below

```
https://xxxx/sites/demoportal/Lists/IT Tickets/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=0x0103008E944F45149824479378A672F53B7635
?Source=https://xxxxx/sites/demoportal/SitePages/FAQ.aspx
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the redirect URL trick using the ?Source parameter still works for Modern SharePoint list forms. You can use the ?Source parameter to redirect users to a specific page after they submit a new item form. The URL structure would be similar to the example you provided.

After the user submits the form, they will be redirected to the page specified in the Source parameter. This works even if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button of a list form.

References: [**Query String URL Tricks for SharePoint and Microsoft 365**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/query-string-url-tricks-sharepoint-m365#redirect-users-navigation-from-a-list).

Comment: Thanks Allen for the response. I'm sure i tried it before and it didn't work. Is it because i was passing the contenttypeid like below?

https://xxxx/sites/demoportal/Lists/IT Tickets/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=0x0103008E944F45149824479378A672F53B7635
?Source=https://xxxxx/sites/demoportal/SitePages/FAQ.aspx

Comment: Actually I got it working . I just appended the contenttype  this way

https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/demoportal/Lists/IT%20Tickets/NewForm.aspx?Source=https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/demoportal/SitePages/FAQ.aspx&ContentTypeId=0x01000DC633E41BD2404BA93026B010B0AEAC0032C059E687BB404D9F75CDD1620E95A7